# creating multiple columns with a loop based on other column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, multiple-columns

Hello everyone I have a working code in python but it is written in a crude way because I am still learning the fundamentals and require some insight.

I am creating 40 columns based on one column like i shared a small part of it below:

```
df["Bonus Payout 80%"]=0
df["Bonus Payout 81%"]=df["Monthly gross salary 100% (LC)"]*0.01
df["Bonus Payout 82%"]=df["Monthly gross salary 100% (LC)"]*0.02
df["Bonus Payout 83%"]=df["Monthly gross salary 100% (LC)"]*0.03
df["Bonus Payout 84%"]=df["Monthly gross salary 100% (LC)"]*0.04
df["Bonus Payout 85%"]=df["Monthly gross salary 100% (LC)"]*0.05
df["Bonus Payout 80%"]=df['Bonus Payout 80%'].apply('{:,.2f}'.format)
df["Bonus Payout 81%"]=df['Bonus Payout 81%'].apply('{:,.2f}'.format)
df["Bonus Payout 82%"]=df["Bonus Payout 82%"].apply('{:,.2f}'.format)
df["Bonus Payout 83%"]=df["Bonus Payout 83%"].apply('{:,.2f}'.format)
df["Bonus Payout 84%"]=df["Bonus Payout 84%"].apply('{:,.2f}'.format)
df["Bonus Payout 85%"]=df["Bonus Payout 85%"].apply('{:,.2f}'.format)
```

the lines of code goes on until bonus payout 120%
how can i tidy this up and convert it to a more coder way?

any help is appreciated

edit :
my first lines of code is :

```
df["Bonus Payout 80%"]=df["Monthly gross salary 100% (LC)"]*0.00
df["Bonus Payout 80%"]=df['Bonus Payout 80%'].apply('{:,.2f}'.format)
```

and the last one

```
df["Bonus Payout 120%"]=df["Monthly gross salary 100% (LC)"]*0.40
df["Bonus Payout 120%"]=df['Bonus Payout 120%'].apply('{:,.2f}'.format)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `f-strings` and `for loops`:

```
j = 0
for i in range(80,121):
    df[f"Bonus Payout {i}%"]=df["Monthly gross salary 100% (LC)"]*j
    df[f"Bonus Payout {i}%"]=df[f'Bonus Payout {i}%'].apply('{:,.2f}'.format)
    j += 0.01
```

P.S.: I have edited my answer after question edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop for that, in combination with `np.arange`

```
for i in np.arange(0,0.4,0.01):
    df["Bonus Payout"+str(int(80+i*100))+"%"]=df["Monthly gross salary 100% (LC)"]*i
    df["Bonus Payout"+str(int(80+i*100))+"%"]=df["Bonus Payout"+str(int(80+i*100))+"%"].apply('{:,.2f}'.format)
```

Comment: I think you need to change `df['Bonus Payout 80%'].apply('{:,.2f}'.format)` as percentage is increasing there as well/

Comment: KeyError: 'Bonus Payout 80%'

I am receiving this error as Abhyuday mentioned